# Bug in JavaScript Code? For loop vs Foreach loop

Tags: javascript

I have the same bit of code written in two different ways, and the only difference between them is that one uses a **for** loop, while the other uses a **foreach** loop. However, they seem to give different results.

Images of the results can be found at the bottom.

The bit of code checks if the **blue** rectangles intersect with the **purple** or the **gray** ones, and if they do, return false.
This bit of code is run each time a new **blue** rectangle is created

The purpose of this is to make sure no **blue** rectangles are outside the area delimited by the **gray** area nor inside the **green** area

```
const USE_FOR = true;

// wall.type: string value, possible values: 'bound', 'base', 'random'
// CONFIG.wall.bound_type: 'gray'
// CONFIG.wall.base_type: 'base'

// 'bound' type: gray rectangles
// 'base' type: purple rectangles
// 'random' type: blue rectangles
if (USE_FOR) {
    for (let i = 0; i < walls.length; i++) {
        let wall = walls[i];

        if (wall.type == CONFIG.wall.base_type || wall.type == CONFIG.wall.bound_type) {
            if (isCollision(wall.getArea(), area)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    walls.forEach((wall) => {
        if (wall.type == CONFIG.wall.base_type || wall.type == CONFIG.wall.bound_type) {
            if (isCollision(wall.getArea(), area)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}

return true;
```

[Result from using the **for** loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4ZNs.png)

[Result from using the **foreach** loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXPPR.png)

Comment: return in for loop exits the outer function. return in foreach loop only exits the anon function inside (which does nothing)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Array.prototype.forEach` your can use `Array.prototype.some` to `return` when your predicate has matched:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

function demoFor(array, predicate, useFor = true) {
  if (useFor) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (predicate(array[i])) return false;
      else console.log(array[i]);
    }
  } else {
    return !array.some((e) => {
      if (predicate(e)) return true;
      else console.log(e);
    });
  }
}
const predicate = (e) => e === 3;
console.log("Using for loop");
demoFor(array, predicate, true);
console.log("Using some");
demoFor(array, predicate, false);
```